# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: java

I have developed a small project in eclipse which makes use of Java6. But I want to run the same project in hpux system which has java1.5. When I try to run it is throwing the error :

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:.

Then I have changed the eclipse Java compiler to java1.5 and jre to 1.5.0_12 then recompiled my project. After that I have deployed once again in hpux system but still it is throwing the same error. I used ant to compile in hpux system. It compiled successfully and produced jar. But while running it is throwing the same error.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version does it say it is? e.g. 49.0 or 50.0. Can you give us the `java -version` on the server?

Comment: Do you have a test suite as well for your app, and does the test suite fully pass on the hpux system, when compiled locally on that machine?

Comment: Does it tell you which class is the problem? Is it one of your classes, or is it a class from a third-party library that's causing the error?

Comment: Are you including some 3rd party library in your project?

Comment: are you sure that the UnsupportedClassVersionError is talking about one of your classes, and not about a class in a .jar file which is on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **target** config option with a value of 1.5 so that the compiled classes are compiled to run against JVM 1.5. Also, make sure that 1.5 is the correct jvm on hpux by manually running `java -version`.

Read more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: If the compiler is "java1.5" do you need to set the target as well?  I suspect the versions are not what he thinks they are.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cross-comilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options) when compiling, specifying a source/target of 1.5, and a bootclasspath pointing to a 1.5 rt.jar